# How to detect (and later - parse) QR code from a picture in C#?

Tags: c#, qr-code, image-recognition

I am now reviewing a rather complex task - how to detect QR code on a picture? 
I have checked such solutions as ZXing.NET, even some proprietary libraries. QR code has a remarkable pattern - it always has three black squares.

Do I need to use neural networks and CUDA for recognizing QR code on picture?

I have found similar project which may be helpful: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1250071/QR-Code-Encoder-and-Decoder-NET-Framework-Standard , but I am curious to know the overall principles and concepts behind it.

What actions should I take to dispatch it on picture, considering that it may be skewed/rotated?

Answer (score 3):

In most computer vision software, it's done way simpler than all the things you describe.

The QR code is black and white, and that contrast is what matters. 
The QR code has 3 big black dots in the corners which are used to find the QR code and the orientation. These are called finder patterns. This picture gives a nice overview:

[image]
[Source, which has great explanation on the concept.](http://datagenetics.com/blog/november12013/index.html)

[More on finder/alignment](http://qrcode.meetheed.com/question1.php)

Data in qr codes are kept with some redundancy, so the same data may be incorporated 3 times, so that any wrinkles or damages to the qr code can still be picked up.

There are lots of resources online. OpenCv (open computer vision) is a popular open source library for computer vision, maybe there is a QR-code module in there?

[Here](https://aishack.in/tutorials/scanning-qr-codes-verify-finder/)'s sample implementation that looks good.